# Is there anything strange about a 4096 bit GPG key?

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I noticed the [GnuPG HowTo](http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/english/GPGMiniHowto-3.html#ss3.1) says "some people say you should have at a key-size of 2048 bits (which is also **really** a maximum with GnuPG at this moment)."  Is there any reason besides computation time why this discourages key sizes above 2048 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read it as discouraging. It says:

> When security is a top priority and performance is less an issue you
>   ought to pick the largest key-size available.

It also says "...key-size of 2048 bits (which is also really a maximum with GnuPG at this moment). ...", but that moment was in 2004, more than 7 years ago.